# classes from c++ to assembly language

Tags: c++, assembly

I can't understand how classes are implemented in assembly language. I inspected the source code of a c++ application( compiler of visual studio ) that uses a class but it looks like a normal code with no special functions or something other. Where is the constructor of this class and how does it work? I guess the parameters of the constructor are passed by stack, but what does function unknown_libname_1 do?

```
.text:00261050
.text:00261050 ; int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
.text:00261050 _main           proc near               ; CODE XREF: ___tmainCRTStartup+10Ap
.text:00261050
.text:00261050 var_10          = byte ptr -10h
.text:00261050 var_8           = byte ptr -8
.text:00261050 argc            = dword ptr  8
.text:00261050 argv            = dword ptr  0Ch
.text:00261050 envp            = dword ptr  10h
.text:00261050
.text:00261050                 push    ebp
.text:00261051                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:00261053                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:00261056                 push    4
.text:00261058                 push    3
.text:0026105A                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_8]
.text:0026105D                 call    unknown_libname_1 ; Microsoft VisualC 2-10/net runtime
.text:00261062                 push    6
.text:00261064                 push    5
.text:00261066                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_10]
.text:00261069                 call    unknown_libname_1 ; Microsoft VisualC 2-10/net runtime
.text:0026106E                 mov     eax, ds:?endl@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@AAV21@@Z ; std::endl(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)
.text:00261073                 push    eax
.text:00261074                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_8]
.text:00261077                 call    sub_261000
.text:0026107C                 push    eax
.text:0026107D                 push    offset aRectArea ; "rect area: "
.text:00261082                 mov     ecx, ds:?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> std::cout
.text:00261088                 push    ecx
.text:00261089                 call    sub_2612D0
.text:0026108E                 add     esp, 8
.text:00261091                 mov     ecx, eax
.text:00261093                 call    ds:??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(int)
.text:00261099                 mov     ecx, eax
.text:0026109B                 call    ds:??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@P6AAAV01@AAV01@@Z@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & (*)(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))
.text:002610A1                 mov     edx, ds:?endl@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@AAV21@@Z ; std::endl(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)
.text:002610A7                 push    edx
.text:002610A8                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_10]
.text:002610AB                 call    sub_261000
.text:002610B0                 push    eax
.text:002610B1                 push    offset aRectbArea ; "rectb area: "
.text:002610B6                 mov     eax, ds:?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> std::cout
.text:002610BB                 push    eax
.text:002610BC                 call    sub_2612D0
.text:002610C1                 add     esp, 8
.text:002610C4                 mov     ecx, eax
.text:002610C6                 call    ds:??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(int)
.text:002610CC                 mov     ecx, eax
.text:002610CE                 call    ds:??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@P6AAAV01@AAV01@@Z@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> & (*)(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))
.text:002610D4                 xor     eax, eax
.text:002610D6                 mov     esp, ebp
.text:002610D8                 pop     ebp
.text:002610D9                 retn
.text:0026
```

function sub_261000:

```
sub_261000 proc near

var_4= dword ptr -4

push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    ecx
mov     [ebp+var_4], ecx
mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
mov     ecx, [ebp+var_4]
mov     eax, [eax]
imul    eax, [ecx+4]
mov     esp, ebp
pop     ebp
retn
sub_261000 endp
```

Comment: It would really help to see the C++ source-code. Without that, it's pretty darn hard to understand what it MAY do (or see the disassembly of the `unknown_libname_1`). [By the way, if you use the "list assembler" from the compiler, instead of a disassembler, you will probably get a more readable assembler listing]

Comment: i'm sorry but i haven't the c++ source code, otherwise i would have posted it. i tryed to post the unknown_libname_1 but for some reasons stack overflow advised me to remove the function, even though i didn't understand why. sorry and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 6):

Assembly doesn't have any concept of classes. When you create an object of class type on the stack, it just makes room for all of its member objects. A member function is just like a normal function, but it is also passed a pointer to the beginning of these member objects, which is the `this` pointer. The compiled functions just access members relative to this pointer. The constructor is just another function that initialises these member objects.

You could think of this:

```
class A {
  private:
    int x;
    short y;
  public:
    A(int arg) : x(arg), y(6) { }
    void print() {
      std::cout << x << ',' << y << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
  A a(5);
  a.print()
}
```

As being transformed into something like this made-up invalid C++:

```
void A_construct(A* this, int arg) {
  this->x = arg;
  this->y = 6;
}

void A_print(A* this) {
  std::cout << this->x << ',' << this->y << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int x;
  short y;
  A_construct(this_cast<A*>(&x), 5);
  A_print(this_cast<A*>(&x));
}
```

The only reason the made-up `this_cast` is there is to allow the `A*` so I can continue to use `this->x` to mean "Access the `x` object of that `A`". Just a convenience for illustration.

Other than these run-time details, the only other effect that classes have is that they place some compile-time restrictions on your code. For example, you can't write code that access a `private` member of a class from outside of it. That's not enforced in the assembly in any way.

Comment: very thanks! this is exactly what i wanted to know. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I have not really an idea what you are searching for :-)

But at first you have to keep in mind:

1) the compiler will try to optimize all your code, independent of your language. For that you will typically see no inlined functions at all.

2) All calculations from constant values will be done in compile time as part of optimization. So you may only the the processing of the values if they are not compile time constant!

3) Initialization of global objects will be done by a simple copy loop at start of your program which is running before main. There is nothing to see from the code itself.

4) You can only see a data structure of class. But here you have to think a about padding and other things.

Sometimes it is a good idea to look in the produced assembler code to get a feeling which type of programming results in which kind of executable. But today most compilers do a really perfect job which makes it nearly impossible to see how the code was presented in the high level language. But yes, it is good for learning :-)

Comment: thanks for the answer but i've found this code on internet and the title of this code was "class in assembly". i haven't the source code in c++. so i only needed to know how do classes work. thanks again